# How can I use Select_sum and Select_max together in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to get the total of each student's scores in all subjects, then get the maximum total score.

This is to get the total scores

```
public function GetsumScore($exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id) 
    {
       $this->db->select_sum('get_tot_score');
       $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id);
       return $this->db->get('exam_group_exam_results')->row(); 
     }
```

But I'm now kind of confused as to how and where to insert the `select_max` query.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to do it.

**Method 1**

The bounce I mentioned below is to show you that you can use select statement as many times as you want. It will become a single query. You can uncomment the bounce if you want.

```
public function GetsumScore($exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id)
{
    //$this->db->select("*"); // Its a bounce too
    $this->db->select_sum("get_tot_score");
    $this->db->select_max("get_tot_score", "get_tot_score_max");
    //$this->db->select_avg("amount", "avg_amount"); // Its a bounce
    
    $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id);
    return $this->db->get("exam_group_exam_results")->row();
}
```

**Method 2**

```
public function GetsumScore($exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id)
{
    $this->db->select("(SELECT SUM(get_tot_score) FROM exam_group_exam_results WHERE exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id = {$exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id}) as get_tot_score");
    $this->db->select("(SELECT MAX(get_tot_score) FROM exam_group_exam_results WHERE exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id = {$exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id}) as get_tot_score_max");
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

The reason of sharing this second method is knowledge. When we need to add multiple queries in one go, so instead of writting different methods or functions, we can do it in simple `$this->db->select`.

You can also call different tables without join with the current one.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I'm sorry @Vickel, I was quite busy that time, I modified my answer and another method as well. And I tried to add some extra infromation.